# What is `@null` compiled to?

Tags: android, xml, layout

If I set a `@null` for example to `app:tabTextColor`  in layout xml `app:tabTextColor="@null"`, what is `@null` compiled to?

Comment: What do you mean when you are saying 'compiled to'? Are you asking what the meaning of it is or what?

Comment: check this one. https://stackoverflow.com/q/9311123/2956135

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is there any diff @null Vs #00000000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311123/is-there-any-diff-null-vs-00000000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context `app:tabTextColor="@null"` . 
Whatever property we define or give is passed to the java class which uses to draw views accordingly. More info [here](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html)

So if we give a button background `android:background="@null"`

we are giving null to our java Button class file which will draw nothing on button background. So it works just like java null passing to some method or property and will compile to null reference same as java.

And [a null is represented by a 0](https://calebfenton.github.io/2016/02/16/how-does-dalvik-handle-null-types/) in bytecode after compilation

Learn [more](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077233/core-java/bytecode-basics.html) about how byte works

Read more [here](https://calebfenton.github.io/2016/02/16/how-does-dalvik-handle-null-types/) for null in byte code

More here for [dalvik](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dalvik-bytecode) bytecode

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure if this is what you are looking for but..

`@null` means that the tabTextColor returns null it is equivalent in java to: `tabLayout.setTabTextColors(null)`

Meaning that there is no color set to the tab text. `@null` basically means "nothing is set".